# How can I make my Jquery Always appear on top?

Tags: jquery, always-on-top

I'm very new to JavaScript and JQuery and got code from a web developer who is no longer with the company. I am also unable to ask this person.

My script is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var tapLocationsNameSpace = function() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.vars = {
            cotswoldAnchor: jQuery('.view-cotswold-location'),
            plazaMidwoodAnchor: jQuery('.view-plaza-midwood-location'),
```

and continues with variables and looks to be data objects.

I just want this whole section that pops up to always appear on top of everything else.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you access and allowed to modify layout page you can put your JavaScript code on the top of other JavaScript codes in your layout page *but under resource links like JQuery.js, etc*

And if you don't have layout page in your project you can easily move your script code and put it on the top of other JavaScript codes.